# Adding gradient to existing components

Tags: javascript

I cannot add a linear gradient box to a component for my game. the way I want the component to be is:
`new component(width, height, color, x, y, type);`
Is there anything I need to add?
So adding gradient is possible?
I tried but it just gets rid of the canvas after that...

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
canvas {
border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var initialized = false;
var myGamePiece; 
var myObstacle;

function startGame() {
myGamePiece = new component(40, 40, "#00ff00ff", 50, 140);
myObstacle  = new component(80, 37, "#cf0000ff", 240, 0);
myGameArea.start(); 
}

var myGameArea = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 560;
    this.canvas.height = 320;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    if (!initialized) {
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        myGameArea.key = e.keyCode;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        myGameArea.key = false;
    })
    initialized = true;
    }
},
clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
},
stop : function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    ctx.fillStyle="red";
    ctx.font="80px Georgia";
    ctx.fillText("You died",125,120);
    initialized = false;
 }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
this.type = type
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.speedX = 0;
this.speedY = 0;    
this.x = x;
this.y = y;    
this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
        crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
}
}

function updateGameArea() {
if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacle)) {
    myGameArea.stop();
} else {
    myGamePiece.update();
    myGameArea.clear();
    myObstacle.update();
    myGamePiece.x += myGamePiece.speedX;
    myGamePiece.y += myGamePiece.speedY;
}
//myGamePicec.update();myGamePiecemyGameArea.start();
    if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 37||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 65) {myGamePiece.speedX = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 39||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 68) {myGamePiece.speedX = 3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 38||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 87) {myGamePiece.speedY = -3; } else if (myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 40||myGameArea.key && myGameArea.key == 83) {myGamePiece.speedY = 3; } else {myGamePiece.speedX = 0; myGamePiece.speedY = 0;}
    myGamePiece.update();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to add gradient to this??? using `var gradient;` and a `new component` or something like that...

Comment: That's a lot of code that doesn't matter. Try to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: @samanime did it can you please answer thanks in advance.

Comment: @samanime did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a linear gradient, you need at least 2 colors, one for `0%` and one for `100%` to transition between them.

Since you're only providing one, you'll need a way to provide another to gradiate between. You could do this by adding another parameter, or by allowing your function to accept an array, an array of arrays, or an array of objects that specify color and/or position:

```
// some possible ways to define the gradients
['#000', '#FFF'] // even gradient between black and white
[['#000', 0], ['#FFF', 100]] // gradient between black at 0% and white at 100%
[{ color: '#000', position: '0' }, { color: '#FFF', position: '100' }]
```

You may also want to allow to specify the angle of the linear gradient.

Once you've passed in the data, it becomes fairly trivial to apply the gradient.

I'm not going to work it into all of your code, but here is an example of what your `update()` function might look like inside of `component`.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 300;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function component(x, y, width, height, color) {
  this.update = () => {
    const angle = Math.PI * color.angle / 180;
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(
      // Do a little trigonometry to rotate the gradient rectangle around the center of the filled rectangle
      x + (width / 2 - Math.cos(angle) * Math.max(width, height) * 0.5),
      y + (height / 2 - Math.sin(angle) * Math.max(width, height) * 0.5),
      x + (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * Math.max(width, height) * 0.5),
      y + (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * Math.max(width, height) * 0.5)
    );
    
    color.stops.forEach(({ color, position }) => gradient.addColorStop(position, color));
    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  };
};

/*
 In this example, `color` is specified by an object with an angle (in degrees, 0 being left-to-right, 
 rotating counter-clockwise and with an array of color stops, 
 with position specified as a decimal percent (0 = 0%, 1 = 100%)
 */
const color = {
  angle: 45,
  stops: [
    { color: '#F00', position: 0 },
    { color: '#0F0', position: .5 },
    { color: '#00F', position: 1 }
  ]
};

(new component(100, 100, 200, 100, color)).update();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The math to apply an angle to the gradient requires a bit of trig, but the rest is pretty straight-forward: you just use `ctx.createLinearGradient()` to create a new gradient, add one or more color stops, and then use that as your `fillStyle` on your `fillRect()`.

There are multiple ways to do this, but that's generally the basic trick.

Comment: It's too complicated. It's very creative though.

Comment: in `(new component(100, 100, 200, 100, color)).update();` what does `(100, 100, 200, 100)` stand for?

Comment: They are the x, y, width and height of the created rectangle. As for too complicated, you could ditch the rotation bit if you don't need it, but that's the only way to specify gradients with canvas.

Comment: Doesn't work on my platform. Upvoted and accepted anyway because it works otherwise.